# need google chrome or firefox automation c#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, firefox, automation

I would need to start a chrome session login to a page then open a url and close chrome.
I could do this in ie but the page is not ie. optimised. I dont seem to be able to automate firefox or chrome . Any ideas ?

ta,
gabor

Answer (score 3):

Any reason why the page needs to be accessed by a web browser? It would be easier to create a web request in c# and access the page that way. Unless you need this for some kind of integration testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenium. It has drivers for IE, firefox and chrome. If you need a tutorial how to start you can watch: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y9iFvpK10fw